# Find the closest html element(at any level) with a certain class

Tags: javascript, html

I need to write a script where, on clicking a product image in an e commerce website we should get the title of the product. We know a selector for both the Image and the Title. For example in this screenshot all items images have the classes: "_396cs4 _3exPp9" and the Titles will have class: "s1Q9rs"

[image]

So I tried the following code:

```
window.addEventListener("click",function(e){
if(e.target.classList.value == "_396cs4 _3exPp9")
{
    var title = document.querySelector(".s1Q9rs");
    console.log(title)
}})
```

But that querySelector will return the first element it finds with that class. How can I find the title that is closest to the event target? Or since the Image and Title must share a parent element at some level, can I find the title based on whether the Image and Title have any common parent or not?
i.e. if I click the first image I should get the first title, if I click the third image then I should get the title for that third product.

I read up on the element.closest() function but that seems to only find the closest ancestor of an element.

I would like to have a generic solution that could also work on other websites given we have the classes for the image and title for them.

Is a solution like that even possible? and if so, any help regarding the implementation is much appreciated.

Comment: There is a general sibling selector `~`

Comment: e.target.querySelector? or e.target.closest?